# What does space mean in Java?

Tags: java

Usually it is a matter of good programming style to use space to make a program look organized just easy on the eye. For ex, between mathematical operations a organized programmer would often put space.

But what I also see is people using camel case. Like outOfBoundException.

**why can't programmers just use space instead of writing names/identifiers in camel cases**?

Comment: Do you mean why *can't* they?

Comment: The example you give, `OutOfBoundsException` is actually referred to as picket case.  Camel case would be more like `outOfBoundsException`...

Comment: A variable madeup words separated by spaces would be interpreted as several variables.

Comment: @user700390 I thought that was *pascal* case?

Answer (score 6):

How do you write your name in forms Doeser or D O E S E R?
object name is an identity thats why we can't use spaces between names.

Whitespace in Java is used to separate the tokens in a Java source file. Whitespace is required in some places, such as between access modifiers, type names and Identifiers, and is used to improve readability elsewhere.

Java has some naming convenstions 
http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Answer (score 1):

A variable madeup words separated by spaces would be interpreted as several variables. The compiler has no way to understand you meant a single variable. In math, single letter symbols are usually used. Ambiguity is present in our daily language but a programming language cannot afford that. Now, the use of camel case to separate words is but a convention.  You might finf underscores in othe languages. Yet, it has little to no effect on the resultant application. Search Google for naming conventions. You may also want to have a look at "convention over configuration" and how indentation with spaces in Python makes a whole difference. Also note that space in Excel formulas mean intersection.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ambiguity.

For example,

```
StringBuilder firstStringBuilder
```

declares a `StringBuilder` variable called `firstStringBuilder`.

But if you write

```
string builder first string builder
```

, then what is the class name and what is the variable name? Should the compiler interpret it as `String builderFirstStringBuilder`? So using space is not workable.

Answer (score 1):

As other Answers have pointed out, if a programming language allows spaces in identifiers, it introduces serious ambiguity problems.

- Any place where the grammar allows two consecutive `<identifier>` symbols is ambiguous.
- Any place where the grammar allows a keyword before or after an `<identifier>` is ambiguous.

It would be possible to design a grammar to get rid of those ambiguities; e.g.

- identifiers must start with a `$`, or must be surrounded by quotes, and/or
- keywords must be all uppercase and all-uppercase "words" are banned in identifiers.

But when you work through all of the consequences of such rules, you will end up with a language that most programmers are going to HATE.

---

> What does space mean in Java?

To specifically answer this - a space separates identifiers and keywords.  Within a literal character or string, it represents the Unicode `SP` codepoint.

> Why can't programmers just use space instead of writing names / identifiers in camel cases?

Because that is the way that the Java language is specified!  And to get a handle on why they specified Java like that, see above.